# Using pagination to call different html pages on the index page?

Tags: php, html, pagination, include

I'll try to be as specific as I can. I have a site with a lot of pictures, and in my index.php file I basically call one file that contains all these pictures like so:

```
<?php include("content.html");?>
```

Inside the content.html looks like:

```
<p2 id="152"> <em> #152 - 06 Feb, 2014 </em> </p2>
<IMG class="displayed" src="images/screencaps/152.png" border="2"> <br /><br />
```

for hundreds of images

What I would like to do here, is split these up into separate pages using (I believe the word is) Pagination so at the bottom of the page there is something that looks similar to:

Prev 1 2 3 [4] 5 6 Next

I would like to have all of these load in the index.php file rather than actually changing pages to load a different set of images. 
Is there a way I can split the content.html into a variety of different files (content1.html for images 1-20, content2.html for images 21-40 etc) and make index.php change which one is being displayed by which page at the bottom the user clicks?

If what I'm asking can't be done, is there an alternative way to achieve what I would like?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want us to give you a worth-while answer, show us what you've tried first.

Comment: Did you save soure of image into database

Comment: No, I've been told a database is a decent way to achieve this but honestly I'm really not very good with databases so I was discouraged from the idea.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to make content.html dynamic -> content.php and then using php control what should be shown, and what not. If you want to stick to your way, splitting to content1.html content2.html etc... not the best way but you can do like this:

```
   $file_to_include='content'.$page.'.html';
   include($file_to_include);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand. I should make the content file a .php file? Alright. But then instead of making separate php files (content1.php, content2.php etc) I can just call which parts of the file I wish to correspond to the pagination buttons?

Comment: exactly you will need only 1 content.php, and inside it the logic of what to show.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Could you tell me a few keywords I could google to practice this? (calling different parts of a .php file in correspondence to different page buttons)

Comment: you can use if statements, or switch($page)... I think the best way is to store the dates, and image sources in a database then fetch what you want from the database and show it, but this will require you doing a lot of research if you're not used to these stuff.

Comment: yeah I'm not so familiar with php I am fairly new to it and trying to teach myself but what you are saying does make sense. I presume in the php file you will assign a page number id to each 20 images so $page1, $page2 etc, though I could be miles off.

Comment: You can use if($page==1){ //put html of the images you want to show here; } elseif($page2==2){ //put html of the images you want to show here; } and so on, but this is in no way the best way...